# Javascript setCustomValidity does not work on Chrome Version 65

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If you want to set the validity with setCustomValidity function as bellow in chrome the message is not set.

```
<input type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Enter Name"
oninput="setCustomValidity('error')"  />
```

As you can see if you run this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/065thz0w/3/) on Firefox  and Chrome you can see that on chrome the field does not have validation message.

In order to see the that something is happening go to firefox open the jsfiddle and input something. After you input something click outside and observ that a red border is added and text "error"  is displayed.

Is there a workaround for Chrome?

**Edit:**
I have logged the [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=828757#c4) on chromium. Please feel free to follow this thread.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug to me. I tried running [the example given in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity), in a [JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/065thz0w/14/). Again, it works with Firefox, but not with Chrome.

```js
function check(input) {
  
  if (input.value == "good" ||
    input.value == "fine" ||
    input.value == "tired") {
    input.setCustomValidity('"' + input.value + '" is not a feeling.');
  } else {
    // input is fine -- reset the error message
    input.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Feeling: <input name=f type="text" oninput="check(this)"></label>
```

---

A workaround could be to use the [`pattern` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) on the input and provide a regex to validate the input with.

I will use the example given in the spec for this. You can set the regex pattern in the pattern attribute, and error message in the title attribute:

```
<label>Feeling: <input name=f type="text" pattern="((?!(?:good|fine|tired)).+)" title="Input is not a feeling."></label>
```

With that, you can use pseudo selector `:invalid` to apply a red border (or anything else) to the input:

```
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Feeling:
  <input name=f type="text" pattern="((?!(?:good|fine|tired)).+)" title="Input is not a feeling." value="good">
</label>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/065thz0w/21/

---

Note: The obvious disadvantage of this approach is that you are no longer being able to use Javascript for validation - and you won't be able to validate the values of a combination of fields.

Comment: good idea I need it to be used on as a form validation :( I have filed a bug on this hope they will get back on this :)

Answer (score 0):

As of May 11, 2022 Google still has not taken action on the bug filed by OP. I have added a comment to the issue with this same content but figured I would post it here too.

I have determined `setCustomValidity` starts working ~1s after the window `load` event in my project, although the timing is completely unpredictable and I can't seem to discern what is actually happening that causes it to start working.

If others come here after struggling with this as I did, I chose to implement a hack workaround rather than haul out all of the code in my app that relies on native validation to replace it with a large library.

It intercepts `setCustomValidity` in the relevant native Element classes. When invoked, it repeatedly tries calling the native `setCustomValdity` until it works, until it has tried 100 times, or until the `setCustomValidity` interceptor is called again from the outside. Feel free to use it in your own projects. It is not pretty, but it works.

https://gist.github.com/hiebj/177b1fcd8c6be85ac8452b7b8d9f8f1a