# setCustomValidity() not working in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, vue.js

I've got a problem when I'm trying to set custom message in my input:

```
<b-form-input
  v-model.number="libpublishingdatefrom"
  someprops...
  oninvalid="setCustomValidity(Vue.prototype.trans('validation.gte.numeric'))"
  class="inputdate">   
</b-form-input>
```

It's working on Firefox browser but on Chrome **oninvalid** is ignored and it still displays custom message.

I've found one topic about version of Chrome [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646085/javascript-setcustomvalidity-does-not-work-on-chrome-version-65), but I have version 74. It's possible they still have not fixed it?

Comment: As you can [see](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=828757#c4) the bug in the issue you linked to is still open - so what behavior did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

try with this one:

```
<b-form-input
v-model.number="libpublishingdatefrom" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(Vue.prototype.trans('validation.gte.numeric'))"
oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
class="inputdate">
</b-form-input>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.